# CentOS - Upgrading MongoDB to 2.6.1 with no internet

Tags: linux, centos, mongodb

I'm trying to install MongoDB 2.6.1 on my CentOS machine that has no access to the internet.  I've downloaded the rpm files from the repo, and when I try installing, I keep getting the **"mongo-10gen-server conflicts with mongodb-org-server-2.6.1-1.x86_64"** error no matter what I do.

I've tried:

- yum remove, yum makecache, yum install
- rpm -e, rpm -i

But it all ends in failure.  Does anyone have any clue what I can do?

Comment: I downvoted the question, because the title does not reflect the question asked. Eg "Packages conflict when upgrading through rpm".

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove ''mongo-10gen-server'' if you want to install ''mongodb-org-server-2.6.1-1.x86_64'', since they conflict.

You could try adding --force to 'rpm -ivh', but you are more likely to make a mess than not.

Lastly, try to install the .rpm with yum:

```
yum install /path/to/mongo.rpm
```

yum handles dependencies automatically, rpm just moans about them